# Tabular with automatic \hline

Tags: tables, rules

Is there a package or simple command that will insert an `\hline` after every line in a `tabular` environment? It is rather annoying to do it all manually, and it seems like there should be a simple way of doing this (it seems to be a relatively common thing to want to do).

Is there something that does this?

**Edit:** In case it does not go without saying, I would also like a line above the first row as well.

Clarification: I currently have something that looks like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l}
\hline
a\\
\hline
a\\
\hline
a\\
\hline
a\\
\hline
a\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

I would like to have something that would remove the need for me to type `\hline` so many times.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

to make a table line followed by a line the markup is `\\\hline` That's only 8 characters so it's rather hard to come up with a less intrusive markup, given that you have to mark the end of row manually anyway. Perhaps `\def\nl{\\\hline}` then you only need the three characters `\nl` at the end of each row.

Comment: I am not sure if this is what I am going for. I updated the question to clarify.

Comment: @soandos Why isn't it what you need? (even though it is not what you asked for) If you are happy to use `\\ ` at the end of a row for an unlined row, surely typing `\nl` at the end of a row for a lined row is no more of a burden?

Comment: I originally misunderstood. It does do what I want, but I was just expecting something else (an environment that did this for me and I just had to use the `\\\` ).

Comment: There is an answer that does (almost) exactly what OP requested in a pre-TeX.SE answer over in StackOverflow [make LaTeX draw a \hline between each line in tabular without using \hline?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3174697/make-latex-draw-a-hline-between-each-line-in-tabular-without-using-hline).  (I don't understand how it works, though, and will post a question in TeX.SE asking for an explanation.)

Answer (score 10):

[How does this TeX code generate automatic \hline's in tabular environments?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130587/how-does-this-tex-code-generate-automatic-hlines-in-tabular-environments)

## Automatic Horizonal Lines in a Nutshell

- Intent is to **keep unmodified syntax** in the tabular environment, yet alter formatting globally.
- This will **change the meaning of `\\`** for all tabular environments (that use `\@tabularcr`).
- **`\@tabularcr`** is the macro you are looking for. It is what `\\` represents in tabular rows except when using the `array` package, see `Array` Package Changes below.

  1. **Clone it: `\let \clone@tabularcr \@tabularcr`**
  2. **Reset it: `\def\@tabularcr{\clone@tabularcr\hline}`**

*Note that you might be better off using `\midrule` from the `booktabs` package instead of `\hline`. Also note that redefining `\\` may mean that you might run into difficulties trying to use `\bottomrule`, because you might end up with undesired double lines below the last row. There is a way to detect the last row, but it is finicky. I will add it when I get around to it.*

## Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\catcode`@=11 % or \makeatletter to change category code of @ to 11 and temporarily to access kernel macro \@tabularcr
\let \clone@tabularcr \@tabularcr
\def\@tabularcr{\clone@tabularcr\hline}
\catcode`@=12 % or \makeatother to restore category code of @ to 12
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
Meaning & col2 & col3 \\
\meaning\\ & col2 & col3 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

### `Array` Package Changes

Note that the `array` package (and any package that loads `array` e.g. `\RequirePackage{array}`) changes the definition of `\\` to

```
\relax \iffalse {\fi \ifnum 0=‘}\fi \@ifstar \@xarraycr \@xarraycr
```

`\@tabularcr` becomes `\@xarraycr`. So just replace `\@tabularcr` with `\@xarraycr` in the code above for compatibility with the array package.

---

## Notes

In tabular environments, `\\` is redefined in the LaTeX kernel at the beginning/end of the tabular environment.

### Relevant Snippets from latex.ltx

See latex.ltx (LaTeX kernel) for details.

```
\def\@tabular{\leavevmode \hbox \bgroup $\let\@acol\@tabacol
   \let\@classz\@tabclassz
   \let\@classiv\@tabclassiv \let\\\@tabularcr\@tabarray}% sets \\ = \@tabularcr

% defines \@tabularcr to look for starred version
\def\@tabularcr{% 
  {\ifnum0=`}\fi\@ifstar\@xtabularcr\@xtabularcr}

% some starred/non-starred code for dealing with table rows
\def\@xtabularcr{\@ifnextchar[\@argtabularcr{\ifnum0=`{\fi}\cr}}
\def\@argtabularcr[#1]{%
  \ifnum0=`{\fi}%
    \ifdim #1>\z@
      \unskip\@xargarraycr{#1}%
    \else
      \@yargarraycr{#1}%
    \fi}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with the array package. Is there another way to do this that does?

Comment: @PeterFlynn See edit.

Comment: The suggestion to "just replace `\@tabularcr` with `\@xarraycr`" will not be correct, that'll kill the optional argument of `\\ ` inside of `tabular`, so `\\[2cm]` will *print* "[2cm]" in the output. Instead one needs to patch both `\@xargarraycr` and `\@yargarraycr`.

Comment: Well, and `\@xarraycr`, but not in the way shown in this answer...

Answer (score 7):

The tabu package offer an `\everyrow{\hline}` command.

However be aware, that the tabu package is not yet supported if you want to go to html output via htlatex/tex4ht.

Comment: Man, this answer should be at the very top...

Comment: `tabu` right now is not supported at all. It's not been actively maintained since 2011. Source: https://github.com/tabu-issues-for-future-maintainer/tabu

Answer (score 3):

If you are used to vim and vim-latex you could add this to your `~/.vim/ftplugin/tex.vim`

```
:call IMAP('ETA', "\\begin{table}[<+htbp+>]\<CR>\\centering\<CR>\\begin{tabular}{<+dimensions+>}\<CR>\\hline\<CR><++>\<CR>\\end{tabular}\<CR>\\caption{<+Caption text+>}\<CR>\\label{tab:<+label+>}\<CR>\\end{table}<++>", 'tex')
:call IMAP('LHL', "\\\\ \\hline\<CR>", 'tex')
```

Then, if you type `ETA` (like Environment TAble) while you are in the insertion mode, it will be automaticaly replaced by :

```
\begin{table}[<+htbp+>]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{<+dimensions+>}
    \hline
    <++>
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{<+Caption text+>}
  \label{tab:<+label+>}
\end{table}<++>
```

And if you type `LHL` (like Line HLine) it will automatically add `\\ \hline` at the end of the current line and begin a new line.

Comment: I'm not using vim... I would like a `LaTeX` solution, not a vim one

Answer (score 2):

A solution with [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{
  colspec = {lcr},
  hlines,
}
 a & b & c \\
 a & b & c \\
 a & b & c \\
 a & b & c \\
 a & b & c \\
 a & b & c \\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With the environment `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`, you have a key `hlines` for that purpose.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{NiceTabular}{l}[hlines]
a\\
a\\
a\\
a\\
a\\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 1):

This code is similar to things I do in an unpublished package of mine that I used for several documents, most of this should therefore be relatively tested; though I never really used these nested. Still, use at your own risk.

Just from looking at the code, nesting `harray` in `htabular` and vice versa will use the wrong specific hooks in the nested environment, so there is at least one known bug for nesting.

---

The following provides two environments (`htabular` and `harray`) which are patches of the `tabular` and `array` environments. It adds a few hooks to them (and keeps track of the current line):

- `begin` is used before the alignment starts
- `start` is used before the first line inside the alignment (might contain `\noalign`)
- `bol` is used at the begin of every line (in the first line after `start`, might contain `\noalign`))
- `eol` is used at the end of every line (inside `\\` such that it's part of the last used column)
- `lastline` is used at the same place `eol` would've been used if the last line of the alignment wasn't ended with `\\`
- `stop` is used after the last line (might contain `\noalign`)
- `end` is used after the alignment ends

Each hook is provided three times:

- common hooks
- hooks only used inside `htabular`
- hooks only used inside `harray`

The common hooks are always executed before the specific ones.

Hooks can be set and cleared via the macros:

- `\htabAddToHook[<specific>]{<hook>}{<code>}` adds the `<code>` to the respective `<hook>`, if the optional argument is omitted the generic hook is used, else you can either specify `tabular` or `array` in it to set the specific one
- `\htabClearHook<*>[<specific>]{<hook>}` clears the respective `<hook>`, if the optional star is given for each `tabular`, `array` and the generic ones, else if the optional argument is used for those specific one (either `tabular` or `array`) and if both is omitted the generic one
- `\htabClearAllHooks<*>[<specific>]` clears all hooks of either `tabular`, `array` or the generic ones (or all if the star is given)

The row count can be accessed via `htabrow`, which is accessible via `\value`/`\arabic`/`\roman`/etc. (but is no real LaTeX-counter).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter
% row counter
\int_new:N \g_htab_row_int
\cs_new_eq:NN \c@htabrow \g_htab_row_int
\seq_new:N \g__htab_row_stack_seq
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__htab_push_row:% >>=
  {
    \seq_gpush:NV \g__htab_row_stack_seq \g_htab_row_int
    \int_gzero:N \g_htab_row_int
  }% =<<
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__htab_pop_row:% >>=
  {
    \group_begin:
      \seq_gpop:NN \g__htab_row_stack_seq \l_tmpa_tl
      \int_gset:Nn \g_htab_row_int \l_tmpa_tl
    \group_end:
  }% =<<
\seq_const_from_clist:Nn \c__htab_hook_names_seq% >>=
  { start, stop, bol, eol, begin, end, lastline }% =<<

% hooks
\seq_map_inline:Nn \c__htab_hook_names_seq % >>=
  {
    \clist_map_inline:nn { tabular, array }
      { \tl_new:c { l_htab_hook_ ##1/#1 _tl } }
    \tl_new:c { l_htab_hook_ #1 _tl }
  }% =<<
\cs_new:Npn \htab@hook@start@@% >>=
  {
    \l_htab_hook_start_tl
  }% =<<
\cs_new:Npn \htab@hook@stop@@% >>=
  {
    \l_htab_hook_stop_tl
  }% =<<
\cs_new:Npn \htab@hook@bol@@% >>=
  {
    \noalign { \int_gincr:N \g_htab_row_int }
    \l_htab_hook_bol_tl
  }% =<<
\cs_new:Npn \htab@hook@eol@@% >>=
  {
    \l_htab_hook_eol_tl
  }% =<<
\cs_new:Npn \htab@hook@lastline@@% >>=
  {
    \l_htab_hook_lastline_tl
  }% =<<
\cs_new:Npn \htab@hook@begin@@% >>=
  {
    \l_htab_hook_begin_tl
  }% =<<
\cs_new:Npn \htab@hook@end@@% >>=
  {
    \l_htab_hook_end_tl
  }% =<<
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__htab_add_hooks:n #1% >>=
  {
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \c__htab_hook_names_seq
      { \tl_put_right:cv { l_htab_hook_ ##1 _tl } { l_htab_hook_ #1/##1 _tl } }
  }% =<<
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_put_right:Nn { cv }

% patches
\msg_new:nnn { htab } { patch~failed } { Patching~ of~ #1 failed. }
\msg_new:nnn { htab } { unknown~hook } { Unknown~ hook~ #1. }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__htab_pretocmd:Nn #1 #2% >>=
  {
    \pretocmd #1 {#2} {} { \msg_error:nnn { htab } { patch~failed } {#1} }
  }% =<<
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__htab_apptocmd:Nn #1 #2% >>=
  {
    \apptocmd #1 {#2} {} { \msg_error:nnn { htab } { patch~failed } {#1} }
  }% =<<
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__htab_patchcmd:Nnn #1 #2 #3% >>=
  {
    \patchcmd #1 {#2} {#3} {} { \msg_error:nnn { htab } { patch~failed} {#1} }
  }% =<<
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__htab_backup:% >>=
  {
    \cs_set_eq:NN \__htab_unpatched_@@array:      \@@array
    \cs_set_eq:NN \__htab_unpatched_@arraycr:     \@arraycr
    \cs_set_eq:NN \__htab_unpatched_@xarraycr:    \@xarraycr
    \cs_set_eq:NN \__htab_unpatched_@xargarraycr: \@xargarraycr
    \cs_set_eq:NN \__htab_unpatched_@yargarraycr: \@yargarraycr
    \cs_set_eq:NN \__htab_unpatched_tabular:      \tabular
    \cs_set_eq:NN \__htab_unpatched_endtabular:   \endtabular
    \cs_set_eq:NN \__htab_unpatched_array:        \array
    \cs_set_eq:NN \__htab_unpatched_endarray:     \endarray
  }% =<<
\cs_new_protected:Npn \htab@unpatch@@% >>=
  {
    \cs_set_eq:NN \@@array      \__htab_unpatched_@@array:
    \cs_set_eq:NN \@arraycr     \__htab_unpatched_@arraycr:
    \cs_set_eq:NN \@xarraycr    \__htab_unpatched_@xarraycr:
    \cs_set_eq:NN \@xargarraycr \__htab_unpatched_@xargarraycr:
    \cs_set_eq:NN \@yargarraycr \__htab_unpatched_@yargarraycr:
    \cs_set_eq:NN \tabular      \__htab_unpatched_tabular:
    \cs_set_eq:NN \endtabular   \__htab_unpatched_endtabular:
    \cs_set_eq:NN \array        \__htab_unpatched_array:
    \cs_set_eq:NN \endarray     \__htab_unpatched_endarray:
  }% =<<
% due to etoolbox restrictions names of macros that are patched in don't follow
% the expl3 naming conventions
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__htab_patch:n #1% >>=
  {
    \bool_lazy_or:nnT
      { \cs_if_eq_p:NN \__htab_unpatched_tabular: \tabular }
      { !\cs_if_exist_p:N \__htab_unpatched_tabular: }
      {
        \__htab_backup:
        \__htab_pretocmd:Nn  \tabular      \htab@unpatch@@
        \__htab_pretocmd:Nn  \array        \htab@unpatch@@
        \__htab_pretocmd:Nn  \@arraycr     \htab@hook@eol@@
        \__htab_apptocmd:Nn  \@yargarraycr \htab@hook@bol@@
        \__htab_apptocmd:Nn  \@xargarraycr \htab@hook@bol@@
        \__htab_patchcmd:Nnn \@xarraycr    \cr   { \cr \htab@hook@bol@@ }
        \__htab_patchcmd:Nnn \endarray     \crcr { \crcr \htab@hook@stop@@ }
        \__htab_patchcmd:Nnn \@@array      \cr
          { \cr \noexpand \htab@hook@start@@ \noexpand \htab@hook@bol@@ }
        \__htab_add_hooks:n {#1}
      }
  }% =<<

\cs_new_protected:Npn \htab_add_to_hook:nnn #1#2#3% >>=
  {
    \tl_if_exist:cTF { l_htab_hook_ #1#2 _tl }
      { \tl_put_right:cn { l_htab_hook_ #1#2 _tl } {#3} }
      { \msg_error:nnn { htab } { unknown~hook } {#1#2} }
  }% =<<
\NewDocumentCommand \htabAddToHook { o m m }% >>=
  {
    \tl_if_novalue:nTF {#1}
      { \htab_add_to_hook:nnn {} }
      { \htab_add_to_hook:nnn { #1/ } }
        {#2} {#3}
  }% =<<
\cs_new_protected:Npn \htab_clear_hook:n #1% >>=
  { \tl_clear:c { l_htab_hook_ #1 _tl } }% =<<
\NewDocumentCommand \htabClearHook { s o m }% >>=
  {
    \IfBooleanTF {#1}
      {
        \htab_clear_hook:n { tabular/#3 }
        \htab_clear_hook:n { array/#3 }
        \htab_clear_hook:n {#3}
      }
      {
        \tl_if_novalue:nTF {#2}
          { \htab_clear_hook:n {#3} }
          { \htab_clear_hook:n { #2/#3 } }
      }
  }% =<<
\cs_new_protected:Npn \htab_clear_all_hooks:n #1% >>=
  {
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \c__htab_hook_names_seq
      { \htab_clear_hook:n { #1##1 } }
  }% =<<
\NewDocumentCommand \htabClearAllHooks { s o }% >>=
  {
    \IfBooleanTF {#1}
      {
        \htab_clear_all_hooks:n { tabular/ }
        \htab_clear_all_hooks:n { array/ }
        \htab_clear_all_hooks:n {}
      }
      {
        \tl_if_novalue:nTF {#2}
          { \htab_clear_all_hooks:n {} }
          { \htab_clear_all_hooks:n { #2/ } }
      }
  }% =<<

\NewDocumentEnvironment { htabular } {}% >>=
  {
    \__htab_push_row:
    \__htab_patch:n { tabular }
    \htab@hook@begin@@
    \__htab_unpatched_tabular:
  }
  {
    \ifvmode\else\expandafter\htab@hook@lastline@@\fi
    \endtabular
    \htab@hook@end@@
    \__htab_pop_row:
  }% =<<
\NewDocumentEnvironment { harray } {}% >>=
  {
    \__htab_push_row:
    \__htab_patch:n { array }
    \__htab_unpatched_array:
  }
  {
    \ifvmode\else\expandafter\htab@hook@eol@@\fi
    \endarray
    \__htab_pop_row:
  }% =<<
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff

% this might be a good idea, this way a `htabular` and `harray` always behave as
% if the last line was ended with `\\` (so should give consistent results)
\htabAddToHook{lastline}{\\}

\usepackage{booktabs}% just for an example

\newcommand\smartmidrule[1] % maybe this isn't really smart :P
  {%
    \ifnum\value{htabrow}=\numexpr#1\relax
      \midrule
    \fi
  }

\newcolumntype\pseudoenum{@{\hskip\tabcolsep\arabic{htabrow}.\hskip2\tabcolsep}}

\begin{document}
\noindent
Putting \verb|\hline| in \texttt{bol}:\par
\htabAddToHook[tabular]{bol}{\hline}
\begin{htabular}{ll}
  a & b \\
  c & d % would have no \hline without the \htabAddToHook{lastline}{\\}
\end{htabular}

\noindent
array is not affected since \texttt{[tabular]} was used:\par
$\begin{harray}{ll}
  a & b \\
  c & d
\end{harray}$

\bigskip
\noindent
Autostyling with \texttt{booktabs} macros and putting \texttt{end} in
\texttt{eol}:\par
\htabClearHook*{bol}
\htabAddToHook{start}{\toprule}
\htabAddToHook{bol}{\smartmidrule{2}}
\htabAddToHook{stop}{\bottomrule}
\htabAddToHook{eol}{\unskip end}
\begin{htabular}{ll}
  my & headrow \\
  a & b \\
  c & d \\
\end{htabular}

\bigskip
\noindent
Nested \texttt{tabular}s aren't affected:\par
\htabClearHook{eol}
\begin{htabular}{ll}
  my & headrow \\
  \begin{tabular}{|c|}a\\A\end{tabular} & b \\
  c & d
\end{htabular}

\bigskip
\noindent
Nested \texttt{htabular}s don't break the row count (but are affected):\par
\htabClearAllHooks*
\htabAddToHook[tabular]{start}{\hline}
\htabAddToHook[tabular]{stop}{\hline}
\begin{htabular}{\pseudoenum ll}
  Some & tabular \\
  points & \begin{htabular}{\pseudoenum c@{}}making\\absolutely\end{htabular} \\
  no & sense
\end{htabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]