# How does this TeX code generate automatic \hline's in tabular environments?

Tags: tables

@AlexeyMalistov gave an answer to [make LaTeX draw a \hline between each line in tabular without using \hline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3174697/make-latex-draw-a-hline-between-each-line-in-tabular-without-using-hline) in StackOverflow before TeX.SE existed.  The same question was later asked on TeX.SE: [Tabular with automatic \hline](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111668/tabular-with-automatic-hline).

Malistov's answer, which successfully generates a line between each row of a table, is to add this before `tabular`:

```
\catcode`@=11
\let \savecr \@tabularcr
\def\@tabularcr{\savecr\hline}
\catcode`@=12
```

I think this redefines the newline character within the tabular environment, so that an `\hline` is inserted, but the code is still mostly just voodoo to me.  Would someone be willing to explain how it works?  Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Breaking the code

```
\catcode`@=11
\let \savecr \@tabularcr
\def\@tabularcr{\savecr\hline}
\catcode`@=12
```

down step-by-step:

- `` \catcode`@=11 ``

  This changes the category code for `@` to 'letter', since `@` may otherwise not be used inside macro names. You'll note that the subsequent line uses `\@tabularcr`, for which we need `@` to be of type 'letter'. Others like to use `\makeatletter` for this (see [What do `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351/5764)).
- `\let \savecr \@tabularcr`

  This makes an immediate copy of `\@tabularcr` and stores it in `\savecr`. It allows you to now modify `\@tabularcr` (subsequent line) yet still have a copy of the older version.
- `\def\@tabularcr{\savecr\hline}`

  Here `\@tabularcr` is actually redefined to be `\savecr` (stored above as a copy of `\@tabularcr` *before* this redefinition followed by `\hline` - the horizontal rule you're after. Why (re)define `\@tabularcr`? From the LaTeX kernel ([`latex.ltx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx)), the definition of the `tabular` environment executes (at some later stage)

  ```
  \def\@tabular{\leavevmode \hbox \bgroup $\let\@acol\@tabacol
     \let\@classz\@tabclassz
     \let\@classiv\@tabclassiv \let\\\@tabularcr\@tabarray}
  ```

  Here you can see (in the last line) that `\\` is set to be equivalent to `\@tabularcr` before starting the actual `tabular`, so `\\` will have the new definition of `\@tabularcr` which now includes an appended `\hline`.
- `` \catcode`@=12 ``

  This restores the category code of `@` to other. Some users prefer using `\makeatother`.

For a reference on what category codes are, see [What are category codes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16410/5764)

---

Of course, the addition of this before a `tabular` makes it global within your document. It's perhaps more wise to contain this within a group (or as an environment) to localize the change. Alternatively, you can define command switches to "activate" this `\hline` automation and "deactivate" it later.

Comment: Thanks.  Perfect.  Sorry--marking as accepted wasn't enough.

Answer (score 5):

That code *seems* to work, but it doesn't. Let's look at an example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\catcode`@=11
\let \savecr \@tabularcr
\def\@tabularcr{\savecr\hline}
\catcode`@=12

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c}
a\\[1cm]
b
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

that outputs

[image]

Let's see why. The original definition of `\@tabularcr` is

```
% latex.ltx, line 5040:
\def\@tabularcr{%
  {\ifnum0=`}\fi\@ifstar\@xtabularcr\@xtabularcr}
```

and already something is to be noted: if one, by mistake or because some code is being shared between `tabular` and `longtable`, types `\\*` for ending a row, the `*` will not be recognized and removed by the redefined command, because the token after `\savecr` is always `\hline`.

So the new `\@tabularcr` leaves in the input stream

```
\@xtabularcr\hline
```

and here's where things go wrong again, because the definition of `\@xtabularcr` is

```
% latex.ltx, line 5042:
\def\@xtabularcr{\@ifnextchar[\@argtabularcr{\ifnum0=`{\fi}\cr}}
```

The token next to `\@xtabularcr` will *never* be `[`, and this is the cause for the bad output of my example.

---

What's the best way to automatically add a rule after every row? None, for at least two reasons:

1. Horizontal rules are not necessary after every row.
2. You can't add `\cline` where you need it.

Comment: Great--thanks for the additional clarification.  I see that though doing something using global commands in this way helps avoid certain errors (because you can modify multiple lines from a single location) but involves tradeoffs because of potential problems later.  I love the fact that LaTeX gives me the flexibility to control content and presentation in the way I need, but appreciate that there are limitations that must be taken into account.

Answer (score 1):

Using this solution with a longtable results in a few missing rowlines (as explained by egreg).  A solution is to set the chunk size of longtable to be greater than the number of rows of your table:

```
\setcounter{LTchunksize}{1000}
```

Note: This happens when using pander to generate RMarkdown tables:

```
pander(df, keep.line.breaks = TRUE, use.hyphening = TRUE, split.table = Inf)
```