# Patching \\ in tabular

Tags: tables

I'm trying to patch `\\` in tabular enviros using `\@tabularcr` as I've read that it uses it internally, and I'd like to simply add `\midrule` on each row (my real-life use is a bit more complex, but simplified here for MWE sake).  I've tried `\apptocmd` as well but got a failure. Please see below. I don't get a failure for trying to patch it this way, but the `midrule`s do not print.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}


%%% patching does not work
\makeatletter
\let\old@tabularcr\@tabularcr
\def\@tabularcr{\old@tabularcr\midrule}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l}

%%% patching in here doesn't work either
\makeatletter
\let\old@tabularcr\@tabularcr
\def\@tabularcr{\old@tabularcr\midrule}
\makeatother

Hello\\
World\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: you are using the array package, so you need to patch another command, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111668/tabular-with-automatic-hline

Comment: I see now tht `\@arraycr` is needed.

Comment: @likethevegetable no, it isn't, and the suggestion to patch `\@xarraycr` in the linked question's answers will not lead to correct results as well (it will kill the optional argument of `\\ `). Correct would be to patch both `\@xargarraycr` and `\@yargarraycr`.

Comment: @likethevegetable I've added my own code to patch `tabular` and `array` in the linked question (it does more than just patching `\\ ` but I guess you could take a look).

Comment: Thanks for nothing that @Skillmon, some good ideas there.